# why does the default argument change?

Tags: python-3.x, function

why does the default argument change in this case shouldn't it be the same always even when I try to change it

```
def myfunc(x,y,z="bye"):
    print("hey :" ,x)
    print("hey :" ,y)
    print("hey :" ,z)
myfunc("meet","bye","yo")
```

the default argument changes

Comment: `default`= _use  this value if no other value is passed_ ... you are passing `yo`... (otherwise that sense would it have? you would have just created a local variable )

Answer (score 1):

Default argument gets overwritten if you explicitly specify its value when you call the function. It applies only if you call the function without passing the variable that holds the default value.

Have a look at this example:

```
>>> def myfunc(x,y,z="bye"):
...     print("hey :" ,x)
...     print("hey :" ,y)
...     print("hey :" ,z)
...
>>> myfunc("meet","bye","yo")
hey : meet
hey : bye
hey : yo
>>> myfunc("meet","bye")
hey : meet
hey : bye
hey : bye
```